# Webpack: handling of static assets with webpack-manifest-plugin in a production build

Tags: webpack, assets, server-side-rendering, multi-page-application

I'm currently in the process of integrating Webpack in an existing serverside-rendered multi-page-application to leverage the modern tools and ecosystem around Webpack.

This has primarily been a good experience but I'm currently struggling with the integration into our serverside code, especially with a production build using *hashing and a flat folder structure*. The basic idea is very simple: all assets are managed by Webpack and with the help of `webpack-manifest-plugin` I generate a manifest.json that is read by our serverside application. And with a helper function I would turn a path like `static/images/logo.png` into `logo-[hash].png`.

This works great for js/css files (where only the bundle name of my entry points are relevant) but I have problems generating a manifest.json file that contains the necessary information I need for the static assets like images and documents.

**Partial Webpack configuration**

This is the relevant part of my webpack configuration:

```
{
    entry: {
        index: './js/app.js',
        "static-assets": './js/static-assets.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "vendor-assets": "dependencyX/assets",
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new WebpackManifestPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : '[hash].[ext]',
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Approach 1: copy-webpack-plugin**

I tried a configuration like this:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {
        from: './static',
        to: isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : '[name].[hash].[ext]'
    },
    {
        from: 'node_modules/dependencyX/assets/img',
        to: isDev ? 'vendor-assets/[path][name].[ext]' : '[name].[hash].[ext]'
    },
])
```

*Problem 1:* In the manifest I only get the key of the new location but no information about the original path at all:

```
"logo.png": "logo.d985ee06aa950d9232f80c09a9e1329f.png"
```

instead of:

```
"node_modules/dependencyX/assets/img/logo.png": "logo.d985ee06aa950d9232f80c09a9e1329f.png",
```

or even better considering my defined alias:

```
"vendor-assets/img/logo.png": "logo.d985ee06aa950d9232f80c09a9e1329f.png",
```

*Problem 2:* as copy-webpack-plugin seems to do a simple copy there will be a problem of duplication. If I reference one of these static assets also from a regular bundle it will appear a second time in the output folder.

**Approach 2: static-assets bundle**

My second approach was to define a bundle `static-assets.js` which references all possible locations of static assets using a `request.context`:

```
require.context('../static', true, /.+/);
require.context('vendor-assets/img', true, /.+/);
```

*Problem:* Like with the copy approach, the resulting manifest only contains the simple filename as key and not the original path.

**Questions**

- Is there a simple way to solve this by configuration?
- Are there other approaches?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this in the end?